# Can you help me with this Entity Framework Error?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am doing my project but I don't know this error is what.

Please help me about this code and this error.

```
TbStudy Ts = new TbStudy();

int yearselect = Convert.ToInt16(cmbyear.SelectedItem);
int weekselect = Convert.ToInt16(cmbyear.SelectedItem);

string monthselect = cmbmonth.SelectedItem.ToString();
string dayselect = cmbday.SelectedItem.ToString();

Ts.Coursename = txtcoursename.Text;
Ts.Time = Convert.ToInt16(txttimestudy.Text);
Ts.Discription = txtdiscription.Text;
Ts.Year = (from p in db.TbYears
           where p.Year == yearselect
           select p.Year).SingleOrDefault();
Ts.Month = (from p in db.TbMonths
            where p.Month == monthselect
            select p.Month).SingleOrDefault();
Ts.Weeknum = (from p in db.TbWeeks
              where p.Week == weekselect
              select p.Week).SingleOrDefault();
Ts.Day = (from p in db.TbDays
          where p.Day == dayselect
          select p.Day).SingleOrDefault();

db.AddToTbStudies(Ts);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This message for this error is:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

and `InnerException` is:

> System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
>          at Office_Of_Planning.IDEU_Form.btnInsert_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Pooya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\امتحان مباحث\Office_Of_Planning\Office_Of_Planning\IDEU_Form.cs:line 49
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>          at Office_Of_Planning.Main_Form.درجمطالعهToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Pooya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\امتحان مباحث\Office_Of_Planning\Office_Of_Planning\Main_Form.cs:line 45
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at Office_Of_Planning.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Pooya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\امتحان مباحث\Office_Of_Planning\Office_Of_Planning\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>          HResult=-2146232060
>          Message=Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TbStudy' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>          Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>          ErrorCode=-2146232060
>          Class=16
>          LineNumber=1
>          Number=544
>          Procedure=""
>          Server=.
>          State=1
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>               at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>          InnerException:

Comment: Can you post the inner exception?

Comment: Did you see the inner exception for details?

Comment: yes I saw the inner exception but not help me about this error.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that you are trying to insert an explicit value for the identity column.

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TbStudy'
```

Perhaps you need to look at your table design and check what the keys are.

Comment: Maybe you should tell the OP to annotate identity key column as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`.

Comment: Could you please indicate whether you found the answer useful or not. Is there more information that you need. Please provide feedback.